# Creating mysql table with explicit default character set, what if I don't?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, default

In mysql 5.x Whats the difference if I do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE aTable (
    id                       BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    aNumber          bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8;
```

with this:

```
CREATE TABLE aTable (
   id                       BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   aNumber            bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=utf8;
```

Notice I am not specifying the character set as default in the first one. I couldn't find anything in the mysql docs.

Comment: Please note that MySQL's `utf8` character set is broken. [Use MySQL `utf8mb4` if you want full Unicode support](https://stijndewitt.wordpress.com/2015/06/15/use-mysql-utf8mb4-if-you-want-full-unicode-support/).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The word `DEFAULT` is optional there - so the two are equivalent, i.e. they set the default character set for the table.

See the MySQL documentation for [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html).  Here's the relevant bit:

```
table_option:
    ENGINE [=] engine_name
  ... other options ...
  | [DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET [=] charset_name
  ... more options ...
```

You can confirm this using the [SHOW CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-create-table.html) command.

Comment: It is optional, however documentation doesn't mention its behaviour if used.
MySQL documentation also mentions that `ORDER BY` clause is optional and we all know that it actually has some known effect.

Answer (score 19):

There are 4 levels of default settings in MySQL: server, database, table, and column.  Using lower level defaults, you can override higher lever defaults.

If you alter a table that has default charset set to something other than what the database has set, the table default will override the db default.

Comment: Upvote for the explanation of the four levels.  I had database and column set, but not table.  Thanks!